# Why are so many different link relations used with Atom?

Tags: atom-feed

My colleagues and I are working on building an Atom feed. We are paginating the feed over many individual Atom documents, and are adding links to each document to allow consumers to traverse the entire feed.

We're wondering which [link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xml) we should choose to indicate links to the next and previous documents in the feed. [REST in Practice](http://restinpractice.com/book/) uses "next-archive" and "previous-archive". [AtomPub](http://atompub.org/) uses "next" and "previous". "prev" is an accepted alias for "previous".

```
<?xml version="1.0">
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <id>urn:uuid:ff31a040-75bc-11e2-bcfd-0800200c9a66</id>
        <link rel="next" href="http://example.com/documents/4" />
        <link rel="prev" href="http://example.com/documents/2" />
        <entry>..</entry>
        <entry>..</entry>
        <entry>..</entry>
    </feed>
```

Is there any reason to choose one set of relations over the others? Which would be most widely understood by consumers. Why is there such diversity?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reason for the numerous link relations:

> Well-defined relation types can be registered as tokens for
> convenience and/or to promote reuse by other applications.  This
> specification establishes an IANA registry of such relation types;
> see Section 6.2.

Machines use them as a way of asserting relationships between URLs.

Here are the different use cases:

- `next-archive` and `previous-archive` are specific to feed URLs
- `next` and `previous` are generic for all URLs

**References**

- [Link Relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml)
- [RFC5988: Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988)
- [RFC5005: Feed Paging and Archiving](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5005.txt)
- [Atom Publishing Format and Protocol](http://xml.coverpages.org/atom.html)